# Embedding a sway presentation into an email?

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, office365, embed

I'm creating a newsletter that will be sent out to all parents and students of my college on Sway and it will be emailed to them. So far I can only find a way of doing this through a link, which will dramatically reduce the times its viewed, as well as ringing some alarm bells amongst the security conscious. I'm aware it can be embedded into html, but is there anyway to do this in an email client, for instance Outlook